# Regex for comma separated string in angular

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to write a regex for angular where we have a list of a comma-separated string with a max length of x for each string. The spaces should be ignored.

Example: EX123,Ex_123,ex23 , ex_123

The regex that I wrote but doesn't work looks like this:

```
/^[.+?]{1,x}$(?:,|$)
```

Comment: Do you mean `/^\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+){0,7}$/`? See https://regex101.com/r/K0WEuj/3

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I  meant max length of each string, not the number of strings in the list

Comment: `/^\w{1,8}(?:\s*,\s*\w{1,8})*$/` was my first suggestion. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^\w{1,8}(?:\s*,\s*\w{1,8})*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0WEuj/4). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w{1,8}` - one to eight word chars
- `(?:\s*,\s*\w{1,8})*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\w{1,8}` - one to eight word chars
- `$` - end of string.